# Which historical person am I

Tags: riddle, history

**Which historical person am I**

> No surrender in my name
>   
> soldiering not the source of my fame
>
> Horses are my thing, you see.
>   
> *They almost eat me.*
>
> I like going outside
>   
> my body may be revealed some time.
>
> Playing *starcraft* may induce me with PTSD 
>   
> who knows, it's tech didn't live to see.
>
> I'm just going to save my companions
>   
> I tried
>   
> after some time they all died.

**Anti-hint:** (*for those who didn't get it and want it a bit more challenging anyway, they can use this hint to trip them up*)

> What do you call it when you throw an ant and its trajectory is stupid

Edit:

> *I* italicised some words *may* need *some* degree of wordplay to be useful

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are

> Lawrence Oates

No surrender in my name

> He would not allow his condition to compromise his companions' chance of survival

soldiering not the source of my fame

> He was an explorer

Horses are my thing, you see.
They almost eat me.

> Oates = (almost) oats

I like going outside
my body may be revealed some time.

> "I am just going outside and may be some time"

Playing starcraft may induce me with ptsd
who knows, it's tech didn't live to see.

> Starcraft was made by Blizzard

I'm just going to save my companions
I tried
after some time they all died.

> His companions later perished

Comment: Well done. For the starcraft bit, I think there is a link to the expedition name.

Comment: Good job! starcraft part is word association, I think someone will get it. The surrender part was from his time in the military where he didn't want to surrender, but your connection works :). Also sprinkled words from his quote in as many places as I could, good catch

Comment: I think the Starcraft part is related to the expedition name "Terra Nova", and there's a character named "Nova Terra" in Starcraft...

Comment: Could the Starcraft reference be "Blizzard"? Should have got this, since I played a bit of Diablo 2 only yesterday!

Comment: I missed the terra nova thing! :), what a coincidence, thats really nice! Intention was indeed to imagine starcraft startup seeing the blizzard logo -> he died in a blizzard